# UIButtonType issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, uibutton

I have created a UIButton by passing an integer value as this.

```
 UIButton* custom_newBackButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];
 [custom_newBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [custom_newBackButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 UIBarButtonItem* newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:custom_newBackButton];
 [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
```

In some of the classes this works but some of the classes it fails with "Invalid conversion from int to UIButtonType". Is this a recommended way to handle this. I have simply use this 101 to get the back button look and feel.

Regards,

Dilshan

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know, that there are more button-types available than the documentation tells us. I just tested it and I found that there are the additional button-types 100, 101, 102, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114 and 115. But back to the question: Doesn't it compile, if you use an explicit cast to UIButtonType, too? Or is it a runtime-error you get?

Comment: The strange thing is it workrs in couple of places. but in one place it results in above compilation warning. Not sure why.

Comment: So does it fail (=error) or do you just get a warning? I'm wondering if there can be a large project without any compiler-warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following button types are officially documented in the Apple documentation material:

```
typedef enum {
   UIButtonTypeCustom = 0,
   UIButtonTypeRoundedRect,
   UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure,
   UIButtonTypeInfoLight,
   UIButtonTypeInfoDark,
   UIButtonTypeContactAdd,
} UIButtonType;
```

Enjoy! Please avoid using direct values. Values of constants might change and break your app.

Comment: +1 for both pointing out the documented enum and advising to use constant names instead of their literal values.

Comment: Yes I also prefer to use constant instead of literals. But the issue here is there is no constant values available for the back button type buttons. So what shall I do about that?

Comment: How would you suggest getting a back arrow button shape then?

Comment: Unfortunately none of the constants provided in the offical API represent the values that are required here.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly casting it to `UIButtonType` should work fine, though the constant is undocumented and would be rejected when submitting to App Store if the reviewer would aware of that.

Comment: The constants are well documented.

Comment: @badcat I mean `101`, not enum values.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Although most developers consider explicit casting of static values to a constant as very bad habit... ;)

Comment: I experienced myself that apps using undocumented functions get rejected, but are you really sure that this is also true for constants? I mean can there really be restrictions on the data I use to feed functions?

Comment: So is there any risk of using it? If so what will be the alternative? Cos those back button types buttons are not available in the enum directly.

Comment: It is undocumented features and Apple stated clearly in the App Store Review Guideline that it "would be rejected." However, the use of constant here might be quite insignificant and subtle and also would be hard, if not impossible, to prove that you are really using undocumented features, e.g. you might tell them that you use custom button with custom images. So it depends on you or your company policy whether to go for it or not.